# Custom HTML Javascript GA Event Code Not Firing in GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm trying to push a Google Analytics event when third party code is executed on our site and simply track this with a listener and send the event.

I've tried various code to see what is happening here, but not sure if this is the correct method or if I should be adding a listener as a trigger (somehow) and then using the GTM events method instead?

```
var event1 = document.addEventListener('bronto:popup-created',
function(){
ga('send', 'event', 'Newsletter', 'Popup Load');
console.log('bronto pop-up loaded');  
});
```

The console is showing `bronto pop-up loaded` as expected, but no event is seen in Analytics.

Comment: How your basic Analytics tracking is set up? Site code using ga(), gtag or Google Tag Manager?

Comment: I'm currently using analytics.js, but believe I have found a work around and will try to post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have now found an answer, using the custom HTML within GTM I'm now pushing a dataLayer event from the event listener and then firing a seperate Event in GTM which tracks successfully.

DataLayer pushed as below...

```
<script>
var event1 = document.addEventListener('bronto:popup-created',
function(){
dataLayer.push({'event': 'Popup Load'});
});
</script>
```